# Accessing the first last item in an *ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm working on a personal application in Ionic in which I am trying to create a alphabetical header/divider for a list of games by checking the first letter of each game, and if the first letter is not the same as the last game's first letter(they are coming in sorted), generate a header.

Here's my firstLetter() function:

```
public firstLetter(name: any) {
    return name.charAt(0);
}
```

And here is my HTML/ng:

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let game of games; let i = index;">
        <ion-item-divider color="light" *ngIf="firstLetter(game.name) != firstLetter(game[i-1].name)">{{firstLetter(game.name)}}</ion-item-divider>
        <ion-item (click)="openGameSummary(game)">
          <h2>{{game.name}}</h2>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-item-group>
```

I am getting an `error that the property 'name' cannot be found.` Which, I assume is because I am using the wrong syntax.

What is the way to do this?

Comment: Is your game an object or an array? game[i-1].name?

Comment: It is an object... so  yeah, game[i-1] will not work. Not sure what my solution is.

Comment: can you show how your game array looks

Comment: games is defined as `games: Array<GameView> = [ ]`, in which GameView is defined as `export class GameView { gameid: number, name: string, etc...}`

Comment: I think you want to change `firstLetter(game[i-1].name)` to `firstLetter(games[i-1].name)` in your `*ngIf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `*ngIf` to:

```
*ngIf="i==0 || firstLetter(game.name) != firstLetter(games[i-1].name)"
```

Because when the first item is loaded, `i==0`, so `games[i-1]` is `undefinded` and it throws the error.

Answer (score 1):

In your `*ngIf` you should change:
`firstLetter(game[i-1].name)`
to
`firstLetter(games[i-1].name)`

notice `game` to `games`.

What your'e doing now with `firstLetter(game[i-1].name)` is that you are trying to access the `GameView`-objects (`game`) property `[i-1]` which doesn't exist.

But if you change it to `firstLetter(games[i-1].name)` you will instead get the `GameView`-object from the `games`-array at index `[i-1]` and then be able to get that objects property `name`.

You also have to check for when `i` equals `0`, because when it is `games[i-1]` will be `games[-1]` which is `undefined`, because there is no element at index `-1`. So as @Duannx wrote in his answer you should add `i == 0 ||` to the start of your `*ngIf`, like so:

```
*ngIf="i == 0 || firstLetter(game.name) != firstLetter(games[i-1].name)"
```

If the first statement, in this case `i == 0`, is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) when using `||` the second statement will never be evaluated and thus you will never try to access `games[-1]`.

Comment: This *sounds* right. I am pretty confident this will work... I'll let you know and mark this if it works when I get a chance to test.